# How to open/convert a CSV in Python so strings are not unicode?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, csv, unicode

I have a CSV file of various columns of numbers and strings. When I open it with `pandas.read_csv` it always gives me unicode. Any way I can get the dataframe into non-unicode or convert them to strings (and keep the float cells as floats)?

I've tried literally every way I can think of, including some answers of similar Stackoverflow questions.

Including:

`df = pd.read_csv('xxxx.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')` That didn't work at all.

I have also tried changing the dtype of that column with `astype(str)`  That didn't work either.

Then I tried defining a converting function to encode it again:

```
def convert(input):
    if isinstance(input, dict):
        return {convert(key): convert(value) for key, value in 
input.iteritems()}
    elif isinstance(input, list):
        return [convert(element) for element in input]
    elif isinstance(input, unicode):
        return input.encode('utf-8')
    else:
        return input

 df = convert(df)
```

When I call `df.index.unique()`, it always show:

`Index([u'row_a', u'row_b', u'row_c'], dtype='object', name=u'column_a')`

But I want them to be all in strings.

Any suggestion? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df = pd.read_csv('xxxx.csv', dtype='str')
```

Comment: Thank you but that did not work either. Gave the exact same output.

Comment: I think there may be something unusual with the CSV you're trying to read, can you post an example?

Comment: Unfortunately that csv itself is confidential information. But there is nothing special about that csv at all. It's created using pandas.to_csv with no special characters or anything. Just English strings in some columns and floats in other columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the problem that pandas is infering some of your columns as "object" type, and if it found at least one unicode object it will infer it as unicode. To solve it you should use to check which columns are unicode:

```
In [1] df.dtypes

Out[1]: 
column1         unicode
column2         unicode
column3         unicode
```

then get the types:

```
types = df.apply(lambda x: pd.lib.infer_dtype(x.values))
```

and convert them to strings:

```
for col in types[types=='unicode'].index:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(str)
```

Comment: All my columns are object, none of them is unicode. And I already tried astype(str), didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Pandas automatically assigns a data type to the columns in your data frame based on the content of the column. If you want to change that, you need to infer a data type for each of the columns. Call this line of code for each column of your data frame.

```
df["column_name"] = df['column_name'].astype('object')
```

In Python, the String data type is equivalent to the 'object' data type in pandas.

For your columns that contain floats, call the following code:

```
df["column_name"] = df['column_name'].astype('float64')
```

Also, here is a [link](http://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html) for additional information on data types in pandas.

You can also check the data type for all of your columns by calling `df.dtypes`

[image]

Comment: All my columns are object, none of them is unicode. And I already tried astype(str), didn't work :(

Comment: @iris Can you try this to see if this would work? read_csv('file', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

Comment: @iris can you also provide a sample of your data? If you can, call df.describe and show the results. Call df.dtypes and show those results. Lastly, check out what happens when you just use read_csv('xxxx.csv') without encoding

Comment: encoding = "ISO-8859-1" doesn't work either.It has nothing to do with the CSV. I think it might be a python or package versioning thing. I just created a new csv with random strings and numbers and it's still showing up as all unicodes.

Comment: I've looked around and found three more possible solution. 1. df = pd.read_csv(input_file_path,...engine='python') or 2.  for column in df:

            df[column] = df[column1,column1,...].str.encode('utf-8')         3. Go to your CSV in Microsoft Office, click Save As, Next to the save button should be Tools. Go to Web Options. Click the Encoding Tab. Select 'UTF-8'.